# Remove permanent redirect and clean DNS

Tags: centos, dns, cpanel

I am experiencing "Server not found" errors since I did the following, in my server I had this domain structure:

- example.com  -> permanent redirection to app.example.com
- app.example.com

I removed the redirection from `example.com` using cPanel, then I uploaded a simple html file stating "under construction" message.

After these changes, I get the error mentioned at the beginning, however I asked some people to test the side. Some guys can see, in fact, the "under construction message", and some others like me are experiencing the error. Then, I assume that there are some cached details that can may affect DNS resolution. At this moment I do not know what to check or do in order from now.

Server CentOS release 6.7 (Final):

> Linux 2.6.32-042stab079.4 #1 SMP Thu Jul 18 18:57:29 MSK 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

cPanel:

> 11.52.0.23

Comment: How long ago did you make the changes?  It can take a while (sometimes up to 48 hours) for DNS changes to fully propagate and caches to update.

Comment: I did it this last sunday.